# NPE while injecting Retrofit with Dagger

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, retrofit2, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger for DI and Retrofit for network.
When i trying to call retrofits api method in my presenter, i catchs NPE.
Here is Network module:

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {
    String baseUrl;

    public NetworkModule(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    UsersApi provideUsersApi(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(UsersApi.class);
    }
}
```

And app component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = {}, modules = {AppModule.class, DatabaseModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(UsersFragmentPresenter usersFragmentPresenter);

    UserDao userDao();

    Retrofit retrofit();
    UsersApi usersApi();
    AppDatabase appDatabase();
    Application application();
}
```

And when i inject api and call api method here, the member isn't inizialized

```
@InjectViewState
public class UsersFragmentPresenter extends MvpPresenter<BaseFragmentView> {
    @Inject
    UsersApi usersApi; // is null

    public UsersFragmentPresenter() {
        App.getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }

    public void loadData(){
        usersApi.getUser()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(observer);
    }
```

[image: debugging]

Comment: Is `App` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @Nitrodon oh, silly mistake, thx you